# UIImageViews are different when using in IBOutletCollection instead of IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Im new in iOS development, and im trying to get an app working in xcode. In my app, i have lots of imageview's which are basically should do the same. First, i started to write IBOutlet to all of them;

```
IBOutlet UIImageView image1;
IBOutlet UIImageView image2;
IBOutlet UIImageView image3;
...
```

But it would be a much better solution for me, to create an IBOutletCollection and connect that to every UIImageView on the storyboard. So i created an IBOUtletCollection;

```
IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *images;
```

But then, i started to get errors in the code, which previously worked with simple IBOutlets;

```
imageToZoom.image = images.image; - "Image" property not found in Array object.
```

And warning such as the followings:

```
[images setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; - NSArray may not respond 'setUserInteractionEnabled'
[images addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce]; - NSArray may not respont 'addGestureRecognizer'
```

I get it, it's not an UIImageView anymore, it's an array, but i have no idea how to resolve these errors. For example, how can i refer to the "image" property of an item in the array. In an UIImageView is't simply "ImageView.image", but it's not working now.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes  ,images is kind of class of NSArray ,   object in this array is UIImageView, so you can do this

```
for (int i=0, i< images.count,i++) {
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)images[i];
imageView.image = images.image;
[imageView setUserInterfaceEnable:YES];
[imageView setGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
}
```